# Exponent $x$ tending to infinity

Tags: limits, exponential-function

When an expression has $x$ tending to infinity and it's an exponent, like:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac 1{2^x},$$
is there some way to get a solid value for this limit (hopefully $0$, but at this stage I'm not picky)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "a solid value for this limit"? The limit exists and is, as you said, equal to $0$.

Comment: I meant a value like 2 or 0 or similar, as opposed to "infinity" or "undefined". Like the answers below tell, I am clearly in need of a good book/teacher for this concept ... !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never reaches a solid value, think of it as the numerator being a constant, and the denominator growing infinitely, the resultant fraction tends to 0.

In any case this is a basic situation that your textbook or teacher will cover and explain, go check it out!

Answer (score 2):

Your limit is 0. I would advise that you read about this in your book. It is impossible that this (and many other scenario you might encounter) is not covered.

Answer (score 2):

$2^x->\infty$ 
$=>$ $1/2^x->0$